# Change width of slide in Slick-Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using [slick-slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)
in my Angular-6 project using jQuery. I want to change the width of the slide on click of that slide.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide" (click)="changeWidth()"></div>
  <div class="slide" (click)="changeWidth()"></div>
  <div class="slide" (click)="changeWidth()"></div>
  <div class="slide" (click)="changeWidth()"></div>
  <div class="slide" (click)="changeWidth()"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my typescript code:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('.slide-container').slick({
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '25%',
      slidesToShow: 1,
      accessibility: true,
      cssEase: 'ease-in-out',
      focusOnSelect: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 350,
    });
  }
  
  changeWidth() {
     // currentWidth is a global variable assigned to '25%'
     if (currentWidth === '25%') {
      $('.slide-container').slick('slickSetOption', 'centerPadding', '2%');
    } else {
      $('.slide-container').slick('slickSetOption', 'centerPadding', '25%');
    }
  }
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
.slide {
  transition: width 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

It works pretty well but the problem is when it increases the width slides move towards left first and then start its CSS transition. Also, when it decreases the width it moves slides towards the right and then starts the CSS transition.

At the time of increasing width, I want it to increase the width from the center of the slide and at the time of decreasing it should end up decreasing in center of slide only.

It is also okay to change CSS properties of Slick-classes. I tried to change according to my need but it is not working as my expectation.

How can I accomplish this scenario?

Thanks.